# Page-based App, UINavigation Controller, Similar to iOS Calendar

Tags: ios, ios5, xcode4, uinavigationcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I want to do use the Apple template for a Page-based App (Xcode 4.4.1, iOS 5) and then be able to "push" pages from the page view...

1. Create a Page-based App
2. Add a button to Data View -> view -> view (The nested view)
3. Add a "Push" segue to a new Controller/View
4. Expect when the button is pressed that it will "Push" to the new view.

But it doesn't, and I don't know how to make it happen.  I assume I need a UINavigationController somewhere, but I'm not sure where and how to insert it.

Note: I can use a modal segue which does what is expected, but not a push segue.

Thanks.

Comment: do you want to 'leave' the pageVC and push a new vc on top?

Comment: @Tobi In the template it's called DataViewController (contains the current displayed page).  It would be like the calendar program.  When you touch an appointment, it pushes to the appointment details with the back button.  When done with details, pop back to the day list.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, and it was one of the two obvious choices.  I added a navigation controller in front of the RootViewController.

I think I missed it originally because Xcode keep crashing so I assumed it wasn't going to work.